# Setting a ngBootstrap attribute from the component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to set my input control it's ngbTooltip from the component.

I have an ElementRef in my code:

```
  @Input() element: ElementRef;
```

And I'm using the Renderer2 to set the Attribute 'ngbTooltip'.

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.element, 'ngbTooltip', 'my tooltip!!');
```

It seems that this code results in the following:

```
<input _ngcontent-c2="" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched" max="63" name="myInputElement" type="text" ng-reflect-max="63" ng-reflect-name="myInputElement" ng-reflect-model="9999" ngbtooltip="my tooltip!!">
```

So it looks it's not converted to a real ngbTooltip, also it's converted into lower case (ngbtooltip instead of ngbTooltip).

Is there a way to achieve the correct behavior by using setAttribute?